# Updating data on an existing ParseObject in C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, updates

I have now solved this issue. I have left the original question / code in place for comparison.

*** SOLUTION ***

```
public static void saveUserData(string emailAddress) {
    ParseObject userData = new ParseObject("userData");
    ParseObject userLevelData = new ParseObject("levelData");
    userData["playerName"] = emailAddress;
    try {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseData = ParseObject.GetQuery("userData").WhereEqualTo("playerName", userData["playerName"]);
        parseData.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
            if(t.IsFaulted) {
                userData["level"] = GameStatus.currentUser.level;
                userData["highestLevel"] = GameStatus.currentUser.highestLevel;
                userData["currentLevelTime"] = GameStatus.currentUser.currentLevelTime;
                userData["version"] = UserData.currentUserDataVersion;
                userLevelData["level"] = GameStatus.currentUser.level;
                userLevelData["playerName"] = emailAddress;
                userLevelData["date"] = DateTime.Now;
                userLevelData["time"] = -1;
                userData.SaveAsync();
                userLevelData.SaveAsync();
            } else if(!t.IsCanceled) {
                userData = t.Result;
                try {
                    userData.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t2 => {
                        userData["level"] = GameStatus.currentUser.level;
                        userData["highestLevel"] = GameStatus.currentUser.highestLevel;
                        userData["currentLevelTime"] = GameStatus.currentUser.currentLevelTime;
                        userData["version"] = UserData.currentUserDataVersion;
                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> levelData = ParseObject.GetQuery("levelData").WhereEqualTo("playerName", userData["playerName"]).WhereEqualTo("level", GameStatus.currentUser.level);
                        levelData.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t3 => {
                            if(t3.IsFaulted) {
                                userLevelData["level"] = userData["level"];
                                userLevelData["playerName"] = emailAddress;
                                userLevelData["date"] = DateTime.Now;
                                userLevelData["time"] = GameStatus.currentUser.currentLevelData.time;
                                userLevelData.SaveAsync();
                            } else if(!t3.IsCanceled) {
                                userLevelData = t3.Result;
                                int timeVal = Convert.ToInt32(userLevelData["time"]);
                                if(timeVal == -1 || GameStatus.currentUser.currentLevelData.time < timeVal) {
                                    try {
                                        userLevelData.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t4 => {
                                            userLevelData["date"] = DateTime.Now;
                                            userLevelData["time"] = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                                            userLevelData.SaveAsync();
                                        });
                                    } catch(Exception e) {
                                        Debug.LogException(e);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        userData.SaveAsync();
                    });
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Debug.LogException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Debug.LogException(e);
    }
}
```

I am trying to update data on an existing ParseObject using C# in Unity3D.  My code is as follows:

Original code:

```
public static void saveUserData(string emailAddress) {
    ParseObject userData = new ParseObject("userData");
    ParseObject userLevelData = new ParseObject("levelData");
    userData["playerName"] = emailAddress;
    try {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseData = ParseObject.GetQuery("userData").WhereEqualTo("playerName", userData["playerName"]);
        parseData.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
            if(t.IsFaulted) {
                userData["level"] = GameStatus.currentUser.level;
                userData["highestLevel"] = GameStatus.currentUser.highestLevel;
                userData["currentLevelTime"] = GameStatus.currentUser.currentLevelTime;
                userData["version"] = UserData.currentUserDataVersion;
                userLevelData["level"] = GameStatus.currentUser.level;
                userLevelData["playerName"] = emailAddress;
                userLevelData["date"] = DateTime.Now;
                userLevelData["time"] = -1;
                userData.SaveAsync();
                userLevelData.SaveAsync();
            } else if(!t.IsCanceled) {
                userData = t.Result;
                try {
                    userData.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t2 => {
                        userData["level"] = GameStatus.currentUser.level;
                        userData["highestLevel"] = GameStatus.currentUser.highestLevel;
                        userData["currentLevelTime"] = GameStatus.currentUser.currentLevelTime;
                        userData["version"] = UserData.currentUserDataVersion;
                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> levelData = ParseObject.GetQuery("levelData").WhereEqualTo("playerName", userData["playerName"]).WhereEqualTo("level", GameStatus.currentUser.level);
                        levelData.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t3 => {
                            if(t3.IsFaulted) {
                                userLevelData["level"] = userData["level"];
                                userLevelData["playerName"] = emailAddress;
                                userLevelData["date"] = DateTime.Now;
                                userLevelData["time"] = GameStatus.currentUser.currentLevelData.time;
                                userLevelData.SaveAsync();
                            } else if(!t3.IsCanceled) {
                                userLevelData = t3.Result;
                                int timeVal = Convert.ToInt32(userLevelData["time"]);
                                if(timeVal == -1 || GameStatus.currentUser.currentLevelData.time < timeVal) {
                                    try {
                                        userLevelData.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t4 => {
                                            userLevelData["date"] = DateTime.Now;
                                            userLevelData["time"] = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                                            userLevelData.SaveAsync();
                                        });
                                    } catch(Exception e) {
                                        Debug.LogException(e);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        userData.SaveAsync();
                    });
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Debug.LogException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Debug.LogException(e);
    }
}
```

Now, I get an output stating the user is found, and creating a user if it's not found works OK. The issue I have is that, although I've specified a userFound bool, the if(userFound) nest is never called.

Can anyone see what I've done (or haven;t done) or am I totally going about this the wrong way?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered that control is falling to the `if(userFound)` block *before* the `userFound` variable has a chance to be set? (You are setting it inside an async callback)

Comment: Ah, no I hadn't even considered that. I'm going to try a different route and I'll let you know the outcome (if I manage to fix it that is).

Comment: OK, That's partially fixed the issue, but now I've got to figure out how to update each level. I suppose I could take that out of the for next loop as it only needs to be updated when it changes (at max. once per level).

Comment: If you have a new question (i.e. the issue with falling to the `if` block is solved), can you update the body of this question? It's hard to tell what the problem is now.

Comment: Sorry! The matter is solved. I will update the original post accordingly.